# No data in activity's layout while using Layout Inflater and view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, oncreate

I'm trying to learn Android doing some easy projects, and now I don't know how to solve this problem:

I have a main activity who has a ListView. In my onClick function, I'm sending to my second activity a parameter called "name". I catch this parameter, and I try to fill my ImageView and TextView.

This is the code of my sencond activity onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String padre=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_ficha, null);
    TextView textView_ficha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DescripcionFicha);
    ImageView imageView_ficha = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.FotoFicha);

    if(padre.equals("cibeles")){         
        imageView_ficha.setImageResource(R.drawable.cibeles);
        textView_ficha.setText("Cibeles");
    }
    if(padre.equals("bernabeu")){
        imageView_ficha.setImageResource( R.drawable.bernabeu);
        textView_ficha.setText("Bernabeu");
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha);
}
```

And my Layout code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FotoFicha"
        android:layout_width="374dp"
        android:layout_height="277dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DescripcionFicha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/FotoFicha"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The question is, why my second activity is empty? I only see an image of ic_launcher and the text "TextView".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: print this object ***padre*** and tell me what is its content!

Comment: I think it does not match any condition

Comment: I think that too... we need to see the padre!

Comment: In debug mode, i could see that padre has "cibeles", and the if statement works fine.

Comment: as a  best practice use setcontentview rather than layout inflator  because u are in activity layout inflator is used in fragment and runtime view attaching check this u will get an idea https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 
`setContentView(view);`

instead of 
 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha);`

because by doing `setContentView(R.layout.activity_ficha);` you are adding an empty layout with activity but your data is inside children of `view`  reference

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_ficha, null);
TextView textView_ficha = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.DescripcionFicha);
ImageView imageView_ficha = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.FotoFicha);
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml file:
Remove this (app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher") and (android:text="TextView") from your ImageView and TextView respectively

Comment: If I try this, I get an empty screen

Answer (score 0):

try this to get the passed string bundle

```
String padre = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

and let me know